# Stanford CoreNLP Server: Reduce memory footprint

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am acessing the CoreNLP Server from a Python script running in Jupyter Lab. I am using the full annotator suite to extract quotes from newspaper articles.

```
request_params={'annotators': "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse,coref,quote",...
```

As against the recommended 2GB, I have allocated 4GB and yet the quote annotator fails to load. Windows task manager shows memory utilization at >94% for long periods.

Where can I get a list of options that I can tune to improve memory use?

Comment: On further R&D: adding the flags `'useSUTime':'false', 'applyNumericClassifiers':'false',` speedens up the process significantly, with max 23% memory use. What other flags can I tune?

Answer (score 1):

The coreference models are probably the main culprit.  If you don't care about quote attributions you can set `-quote.attributeQuotes false` and not use coref, but you will lose quote attributions.

I'm not sure the exact amount, but I think you should be fine in the 6GB-8GB range for running the entire pipeline presented in your question.  The models used do take up a lot of memory.  I don't think the options you have set in your comment ("useSUTime", "applyNumericClassifiers") will affect memory footprint at all.

Comment: Many thanks. Where can I access a full list of switches?